# Warning while loading XML feed from other site

Tags: php

```
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();

$url = 'http://domain.com/london/rss';

$key='item';

if($xmlDoc->load($url))

{
    $items = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName($key);
    if($items)
        {
            for($i=0; $i<$items->length; $i++)
                {
                    foreach($items->item($i)->childNodes as $childnode){
                        echo $childnode->nodeValue;
                    }
                }
        }
}
```

I use the above code to grab the details from the remote xml, but while load the xml it displays the below warning message in the **client server**.

**Same code is working fine in my local machine and other servers.**

```
Warning: DOMDocument::load() [domdocument.load]: Document is empty in http://domain.com/london/rss, line: 1 in /var/sites/d/mydomain.com/public_html/loadXML.php on line 5

Warning: DOMDocument::load() [domdocument.load]: Start tag expected, '<' not found in http://domain.com/london/rss, line: 1 in /var/sites/d/mydomain.com/public_html/loadXML.php on line 5
```

Comment: What happens when you `wget http://domain.com/london/rss` from the server and view it? Does it look like valid XML?

Comment: Is there a firewall or proxy between the server and the outside world that is blocking the request?

Comment: the actual url is http://kgbdeals.co.uk/london/rss. Its working fine in my local machine and other servers

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is quite self-explanatory: the document does not exist or is empty. Most likely, you get a 404 error (file not found) or the result is not an XML document.  Put the URL into the browser's address bar - and see what you get.

I used your example with url `http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/ookl.xml` and it worked just fine - without any errors.

Comment: OP claimed that this works on his local machine so it's doubtful putting the URL into the browser's address bar will yield any more information. Getting the URL **from the server** would be the better advice.